# standard way to deal with relative paths in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, relative-path

Node.js path resolve system make me mad. I have 
`var a = '../data/data.db'` path to a file but this path resolve differently depending from am I run this code from node.js directly or from test runner or from CI. Is there is a standard unified way how relative paths need to be managed in node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html) property and [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to). `__dirname` gives you the path to the scripts location as opposed to the current execution location, and `path.resolve` cleans up the relative path.

```
var path = require('path');
var a = path.resolve(__dirname, '../data/data.db');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can use global variable such as __dirname which points to the directory the currently executing script resides.